# Jquery simple manipulation tabs not working in jsp

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jsp

I was trying out jquery tabs where the user can add tabs and remove tabs.I found one suiting to my needs here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation

I tried this out in a jsp page in the starting.When I run the app it throws an exception telling:

The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /Items.jsp(34,32) #{...} is not allowed in template  text
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:706)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$ELExpression.accept(Node.java:958)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2417)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1763)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:347)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:589)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

The line (34,32) has

```
<a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span>
```

But when I pasted the code in an html page it runs just fine..
Why is this behaviour?? Can anyone explain
Thanks:)

Comment: it looks, from the error, that there is invalid text in the template text. I know this seems obvious, but without any other code, that's all we have to go on.

Comment: @Alastair- you can see the code in the link I have given above...Its the same code I tried out in jsp page..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is JSPs use expression-language (EL) tags `${}` for variables and classes.  While `#{}` isn't the JSP EL tag, it is the tag for it's successor, Facelets and it throws the error saying it isn't allowed in JSPs. You will have to use some other method to define your variable section that will be replaced in the regex replace.

Instead of using

```
<a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span>
```

try something like

```
<a href='~href~'>~label~</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span>
```

and change the regex replace line from

```
li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ) ),
```

to

```
li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /~href~/g, "#" + id ).replace( /~label~/g, label ) ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<a href="#href">Give Label Here</a>
```

Comment: @Jigar- Its not taking the **<a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a>**

Comment: I meant `<a href="#href">Give Label Here</a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
                    tabTemplate: '<li><a href="<%= "#" %>{href}"><%= "#" %>{label}</a> <a href="#" class="remove">x</a></li>',
                    add: function(event, ui) {
                        var tab_content = $tab_content_input.val() || 'Tab '+tab_counter+' content.';
                        $(ui.panel).append('<p>'+tab_content+'</p>');
                    }
                    });
```